# Bash script: passing a "string with empty space" onto a command

Tags: bash, maven

I have following bash script:

```
set -o xtrace
TEST_CASE=@Login
mvn clean install --Dcucumber.options="--tags ${TEST_CASE}"
```

When i run the script the mvn command become:

```
mvn clean install '-Dcucumber.options=--tags @Login'
```

Note that the single quote is wrapping the whole -D argument, and the original double quote has disappear.  But what i want to see is below:

```
mvn clean install -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Login"
```

What is wrong with my original script?  how should I update to make it right?

Comment: It seems you're looking at the shell debug output from `set -x`? If so, what you see is correct. The space is still protected and the whole 'word' `--Dcucumber.options="--tags ${TEST_CASE}"` is seen as a single unit, which is the result of abutting two string "types", the unquoted `--Dcucumber.options=` and the quoted `"--tags ${TEST_CASE}"`. If there was a space between them, then you'd see (with `set -x`), `'--'Dcucumber.options=' '--tags @Login'`. Is there really a problem with you code or is this "artifact" just confusing (which I totally understand ;-)). ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the bash script not working? I'd say use single quotes for literal strings and double quotes for strings that are going to be expanded.

```
TEST_CASE='@Login'
mvn clean install --Dcucumber.options="--tags ${TEST_CASE}"
```

What are the error messages?
I think problem is that the quotes aren't actually being included int he cucumber options. So Try this as well:

```
TEST_CASE='@Login'
CUCE_OPTS='"--tags '${TEST_CASE}'"'
mvn clean install --Dcucumber.options=${CUCE_OPTS}
```

Comment: Thanks, i used below command, it works                                                                       CUKE_OPTS="--tags ${TEST_CASE}"
mvn clean install -Dcucumber.options="${CUKE_OPTS}"

Answer (score 2):

The quotes are not part of the argument; they are there solely to prevent the shell from breaking the string beginning with `--D` into two arguments to be passed to `mvn`. The following are all equivalent, creating three arguments:

```
mvn clean install --Dcucumber.options="--tags ${TEST_CASE}"
mvn clean install "--Dcucumber.options=--tags ${TEST_CASE}"
mvn clean install --Dcucumber.options=--tags" ${TEST_CASE}"
```

The following creates *4* arguments, since the whitespace between `tags` and the parameter is not quoted:

```
mvn clean install --Dcucumber.options=--tags "${TEST_CASE}"
```

You can quote the space individually in a variety of ways to preserve the 3-argument command. (Remember, adjacent strings are automatically concatenated):

```
mvn clean install --Dcucumber.options=--tags" ""${TEST_CASE}"
mvn clean install --Dcucumber.options=--tags' '"${TEST_CASE}"
mvn clean install --Dcucumber.options=--tags\ "${TEST_CASE}"
```

For consistency, `set -x` always shows a string that would need to be quoted using `'...'` and quoting the *entire* string, not just a portion of it.

Comment: ... Or `mvn clean install --Dcucumber.options=--tags\ "${TEST_CASE}"`.